# Using mpdf library in codeigniter return error

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

Error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
>
> Filename: libraries/mpdf.php
>
> Line Number: 22307

Backtrace:

File: D:\xamp\htdocs\ci_test\application\libraries\mpdf.php
Line: 22307
Function: preg_match

File: D:\xamp\htdocs\ci_test\application\libraries\mpdf.php
Line: 13118
Function: ReadCharset

File: D:\xamp\htdocs\ci_test\application\controllers\Welcome.php
Line: 28
Function: WriteHTML

File: D:\xamp\htdocs\ci_test\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

this is my controller

```
    $this->load->library('mpdf');

    $html = $this->load->view('welcome_message');

    $this->mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $this->mpdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try loading view likr this,

```
$html = $this->load->view('welcome_message','',TRUE);
                                               ^ will get the value to variable.
```